# Не получается добавить компонент на палитру компонентов

Tags: c#, visual-studio, компоненты

Создал свой компонент на базе TextBox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
namespace ItemButton
{
    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    [Description("Поле с выбором") ]
    public partial class ItemButton: TextBox
    {
        private int currIndex = -1;
        public ItemButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            Size = new Size(50, 25);
        }

        private StringCollection items = new StringCollection();

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility (DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [Editor( "System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing")]
        public StringCollection Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set { items = value; }

        }

        public void NextValue()
        {
            currIndex +=1;
            if (currIndex >= Items.Count) currIndex = 0;
            Text = items[currIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Но при добавлении в палитру комопнентов через меню Choose Items вылетает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]